# How to move data from one table to another table using prepare method in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have 2 tables in My database and I want to move data from one table to another table.

**columns are**

`question_answer= id,question,answer,added_by,added_on`

and

`unknown_question=id,question,answer,added_on`

On a button click, I want to move data from `unknown_question` to `question_answer` So below is my update question function which is currently working.

```
function updateQuestion($question_id)
{

    if (canUpdateQuestion()) {
        global $errors, $question, $answer, $isEditting; // pull in global form variables into function
        $errors = validateUnknownQuestion($_POST, ['update_question','answer']); // validate form
        if (count($errors) === 0) {
            // receive form values
            $question = $_POST['question'];
            $answer = $_POST['answer'];
            $sql = "UPDATE unknown_question SET question=?, answer=? WHERE id=?";
            $result = modifyRecord($sql, 'ssi', [$question, $answer, $question_id]);

            if ($result) {
                $_SESSION['success_msg'] = "Unknown Question successfully updated". CHECKMARK;
                $isEditting = false;
                header("location: " . BASE_URL . "pages-unknown-question-list.php");
                exit(0);
            } else {
                $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Something went wrong. Could not save Unknown question in Database";
            }
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "You do not have permission to Edit Unknown question!!";
        header("location: " . BASE_URL . "pages-unknown-question-list.php");
        exit(0);
    }

}
```

here what I am trying

```
// ACTION: Move question
    if (isset($_GET['move_question'])) {
        $question_id = $_GET['delete_question'];
        deleteQuestion($question_id);
    }


    function moveToMainQuestion($question_id)
    {

        if (canUpdateQuestion()) {
            global $question// pull in global form variables into function
            
            $sql = "INSERT INTO question_answer SELECT question , answer FROM unknown_question WHERE id=?";
            $result = modifyRecord($sql, 'i', [$question_id]);

            if ($result) {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM unknown_question WHERE id=?";
                
                $result = modifyRecord($sql, 'i', [$question_id]);
                
                if ($result) {
                    $_SESSION['success_msg'] = "Question Moved successfully". CHECKMARK;
                    header("location: " . BASE_URL . "pages-unknown-question-list.php");
                    exit(0);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Something went wrong. Could not save Unknown question in Database";
            }
            
        } else {
            $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "You do not have permission to Edit Unknown question!!";
            header("location: " . BASE_URL . "pages-unknown-question-list.php");
            exit(0);
        }

    }
```

And my prepare medhod

```
function modifyRecord($sql, $types, $params)
    {
        global $conn;
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Under normal circumstances you may use ( Step 1) insert into table2 (field1, field2, ....) select field1, field2.... from table1 where [condition], and then if you want to delete the record from table1:  (Step 2) delete from table1 where [condition]. Of course if possible please use PDO or MySQLi prepared statements to avoid SQL injection problem when you do such steps.

Comment: Can you show me an example ?